# Specifying new folder for .txt path in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to create folders named [Cell Value 1] then inside those folders create text files named [Cell Value 1]&[Cell Value 2] with content [Cell Value 3].

I have written a working code to make the .txt files named and with the content, but I can't figure out how to make the folders for the .txt files to be stored in.

Example table

| Last Name | First Name | Birthday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | John | 1/2/1980 |
| Pearson | Sam | 5/4/1974 |
| Smith | Jane | 12/5/1962 |

My Current outputs are John Smith txt with content 1/2/1980
Sam Pearson.txt with content 5/4/1974
Jane Smith.txt with content 12/5/1962

I want these to be categorized into Folders by last name so the output should be
Folder:Smith with contents John Smith txt and Jane Smith txt
Folder:Pearson with contents Sam Pearson txt

This is my code so far

```
Sub create_Txt()
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object

Dim i&, lastRow&
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\mason\Desktop\" & Cells(i, 3) & " " & Cells(i, 2) 
    & ".txt")
    oFile.WriteLine Cells(i, 4).Value
    oFile.Close 
Next i
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub create_Txt()
    Const BASE_PATH = "c:\temp\test\" ' "C:\Users\mason\Desktop\"
    ' It is more convenient to work with objects using early binding. Subsequently can be changed to late binding if needed
    ' set reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, oFolder As Scripting.Folder, oFile As Scripting.TextStream
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject  ' CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, path As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)   'replace with your own 
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 2 To lastRow    'start from 2 - skip header
            path = BASE_PATH & .Cells(i, 1)                             'append path with lastname
            If Not fso.FolderExists(path) Then fso.CreateFolder path    'make folder
            Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(path & "\" & .Cells(i, 2) & " " & .Cells(i, 1) & ".txt")
            oFile.WriteLine .Cells(i, 3).Value
            oFile.Close
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Data**
[image]

**Result**
[image]